# How to implement a LSTM for multilabel classification problem?

Tags: classification, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory

I would like to develop an LSTM because I have a variable input matrix. I am zero-padding to a specific length of 800.

However, I am not sure of how to classify a certain situation when each input matrix has multiple labels inside, i.e. `0`, `1` and `2`. Do I need to use multi-label classification?

[image]

#### Data shape

```
(250,800,4)

x_train(150,800,4)
y_train(150,800,1)
x_test(100,800,4)
y_test(100,800,1)
```

[image]

#### Building LSTM

```
model = Sequential()    
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=))    
model.add(Dropout(0.5))    
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))    
model.add(Dense(800, activation='softmax'))    
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am not sure of how to build the LSTM for training and test. If I train my model with a 3D shape. It will mean that for real time predictions I should also have a 3D shape, but the idea is to have a 2D matrix as an input.